# Rterm.,exe and tcl86.dll

Tags: r, rstudio

Godd morning!

On friday while I was doing some tests using parallel processing (with doParallel, compiler and foreach packages) suddenly I began to have repeteadly the following message

[Message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBvvW.png)

which traduced says:

"It was not possible to find the access point (or point of entry) to the proccedure deflateSetHeader in the dynamic link library C:PROGRA~1\R\R-3.4~1.2\Tcl\bin64\tcl86.dll "

The R version I was using when it started was the prior 3.3.3

I thought that, may be I didn't realize any inconsistency with that version and the packages I mentioned.

I reinstalled everything (R - the most recent version and RStudio, also, the most recent version) and the problem continues even in its most basic installation state (with no extra package installed). And now the message appears even when I just open RStudio but I'm not running anything.

Is anyone having this trouble? how can I solve it?

If any other info is needed I'll be glad to give you. I appreciate any help sice it's been a long weekend trying to solve it.

Comment: Try to run R instead of RStudio and check if this Error Message still pops up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by reinstalling R and R studio latest update. Currently using this version
RStudio-1.1.383
R-3.4.2-win

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW1z7.png)